# postgresql ERROR: syntax error at or near "PRIMARY"

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, ddl, create-table

I'm new to PostgreSQL. I've been trying to create tables in a database but some queries give weird errors. the first snippet throws  a syntax error but when I add "serial" on the problematic column the error is resolved. Should all primary keys auto-increment in PostgreSQL?

```
CREATE TABLE songplays(
   songplay_id PRIMARY KEY, --This does not work, it throws syntax error at or near "PRIMARY"
   start_time VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
   user_id VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
   level VARCHAR (355) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
   song_id VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL NOT NULL,
   artist_id VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL NOT NULL,
   session_id VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL NOT NULL,
   location VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL NOT NULL,
   user_agent VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL NOT NULL
);
```

This works added serial constraint on songplay_id

```
CREATE TABLE songplays(
   songplay_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
   start_time VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
   user_id VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
   level VARCHAR (355) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
   song_id VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL NOT NULL,
   artist_id VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL NOT NULL,
   session_id VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL NOT NULL,
   location VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL NOT NULL,
   user_agent VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Should all primary keys auto-increment in PostgreSQL?*

No, not necessarily.

In the first statement you are not specifying a data type for the column, if you don't want it to be an auto increment, simply use integer:

```
 songplay_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
```

---

Note that `serial` is not a "constraint", it's a data type definition which is a shortcut for an integer column that takes its default value from a sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Postgres [`create table` syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) is:

```
CREATE [ [ GLOBAL | LOCAL ] { TEMPORARY | TEMP } | UNLOGGED ] TABLE [ IF NOT EXISTS ] table_name ( [
  { column_name data_type [ COLLATE collation ] [ column_constraint [ ... ] ]
    | table_constraint
    | LIKE source_table [ like_option ... ] }
    [, ... ]
] )
```

Every column definition starts with a column name, followed by a data type. The first column in your first statement fails to that:

```
songplay_id PRIMARY KEY
```

If not using special datatype `SERIAL`, you still have to provide a data type, for example:

```
 songplay_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
```